# Changing from Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 to Bionic Beaver

Tags: 18.04, budgie

So for some reason I thought Budgie was a cool flavor to go with but I didn't like the DE and switched to Gnome within a few days. There's really no point of having the flavor now and I wanna change it to Bionic Beaver 18.04. Is this possible without losing all of my packages which I assume happens if I install Bionic Beaver 18.04 from scratch.
Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Bionic Beaver relates to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and applies if you're using the Budgie desktop or GNOME desktop.  You can just `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and add the default GNOME desktop to your existing machine, at login select which you want to use for that session.  It uses more disk space (as you'll have both), you'll have larger updates (both will update), but I like this (it can also complicate menus, as you'll have more programs installed...)

Comment: If you install using 'something else & ensure you don't format your partitions (ie. just overwrite them), the installer takes note of your installed programs, wipes system directories & installs your new Ubuntu, then restores the programs you had installed before (or added by you if from Ubuntu sources). It doesn't touch your settings or files either (but backup anyway & ensure you do not accidentally select format!)

Answer (score 1):

Bionic Beaver relates to [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes), being a codename for the release and applies if you're using the Budgie desktop, GNOME or any other desktop.  All updates are stored in a 'bionic' directory on `archive.ubuntu.com` (or country/local mirrors)

You could just

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

and add the default GNOME desktop to your existing machine. At login you can select which you want to use for that session.

Having multiple DEsktops uses more disk space (as you'll have both), you'll have larger updates (both will upgrade), it can also complicate menus, as you'll have more programs installed (that can do the same thing unless both desktops use the same programs), but I like this and have it on my own systems.

If you install using 'something else' & ensure you don't format your partitions (*ie. select the same partitions, just overwriting them*), the installer takes note of your installed programs, wipes system directories & installs your new Ubuntu into those system directories, then restores the programs you had installed before (or added by you if from Ubuntu sources). It doesn't touch your settings or files either (but this doesn't mean you shouldn't backup - do it always in case of power outage, or accidently formatting your partitions)

Comment: Does this mean you should load keep loading desktops onto your machine - absolutely not.  The more 'bloat' we add to our systems, the more likely we'll run into problems (which is one reason a single desktop is safest for newbies), and each is tested on it's own - so you're more likely to come across problems with multiple desktops than if you use just one.  But I do like selecting the desktop I use at login by mood, or what I need to accomplish today.